# Issues with installing nodeJS on a shared hosting plan

Tags: node.js, ssh, shared-hosting, nvm

Here are the steps I am following:

First, I login to my account using SSH.

Then, I install nvm using

```
wget -qO- https://cdn.rawgit.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | bash
```

Then, I restart the shell

Then, I install node using

```
nvm install stable
```

[image]

But, when I check for the version of the node using the following, it says 'command not found'

```
node --version
```

If it helps, here are other things I tried:

```
nvm list
```

[image]

Also, here are the contents of the .nvm folder  (which is inside the root folder):

[image]

I suppose N/A indicates that node is not available.

To sum it up, is it possible at all to use node.js on a shared hosting plan? If, yes, what can I do to make it work?

PS: I have been getting suggestions to use other plans like Heroku etc. Although, I have already invested a lot in this shared hosting plan (on GoDaddy), so I would really like if I can host nodeJS applications here.

PPS: I am new to programming, so please bear with any ignorance.

Answer (score 3):

Try installing node like this

```
nvm install node
```

Then, crucially

```
nvm alias default node
```

Now running

```
node -v
```

Should display correctly

Answer (score -2):

First of all shared server wont allow you to install anything on their server.

If you can able to install node on your shared server then you are pretty lucky.

To run `node --version` command, the `node` command should be in your path. On shared server, it might not be allowed.

So I think you need to check with full path like `/usr/bin/node --version'
(check your installation path)